# How can I stop customers from writing reviews on products?

Tags: magento-1.8, module, review

I don't want customers to be able to review my products. How can I stop this?

Comment: if you don't want this feature, then disable it. you can do it through `system > configuration > advanced`

Comment: ok i posted it as answer. Please accept the answer that helped you. Dont leave your question as it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the backend of your magento site.

Go to System >configuration. Scroll down to advanced and click it.

From there you will find **Mage_Review**. Disable this.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want that feature, the fastest way to remove this feature would be disable that module. You can disable a module in mainly two ways.

### 1) Through admin side

For this go to `System > Configuration > Advanced`. There you can see all modules that are using by magento. Disable the one you need

### 2) Through module activation File

Go to the directory `app/etc/modules`. There all modules activation files are present. Select the right one and put `false` in `active` node

Here the name of module that need to disable is `Mage_Review`

Comment: yep. But my comment helped you really :)

Comment: @steven lynn's answer was the first I saw. His solution worked so I accepted his answer. If I could accept both I would. They are the same answer.

Comment: His answer was posted before you comment. It was helpful. I see. Sorry I thought you were upset.

Comment: ah.. yes.. he answered just one minute before. I didn't see any answer when i put comment there. So misunderstood that I have commented first. Sorry for that. But.. I am not upset friend.  I may become upset if you leave this question as it is. Since you didn't do that it should appreciated. That's what I meant and did.